# How to use GridView inside InteractiveViewer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a game map using an `InteractiveViewer` for the panning/zooming and then a
`GridView` to generate the grid of rows and columns. This is my `build` function:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
        constrained: false,
        transformationController: _transformationController,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: widget.map.columns,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children:
              List.generate(widget.map.rows * widget.map.columns, (index) {
            return Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
                child: Text(index.toString()));
          }),
        ));
  }
```

However when running this code I keep getting errors such as:

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1753 pos 16:
> 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true.
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
> more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
> In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> GridView

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#078ce relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
> The relevant error-causing widget was
> GridView

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#07bb5 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
> The relevant error-causing widget was
> InteractiveViewer

I thought that setting `shrinkWrap: true` and removing the scroll would solve this but it hasn't. Using a `Table` like in [this](https://github.com/justinmc/flutter-interactive-viewer-demos/blob/master/lib/table/table_page.dart) example works but I want to use a `GridView` as it's a lot cleaner and easier to work with in my opinion.

How can I fix this?

Comment: hey mate did you find any way to make this possible, I've the same issue.

Comment: @D_Alpha No I abandoned this project unfortunately.